# Restore cursor position after executing make

Tags: vim

Assume the cursor is at horizontal position 42 of a line. Then you go into normal mode and execute the command

```
:mak
```

which will call `make`. After `make` is executed you return to normal mode but your cursor is positioned at horizontal position 0 (assuming that no whitespace is contained at the beginning of the line) of the same line.

Is it possible to tell vim that it should return to the same horizontal position of the same line as before executing `make`?

I played with settings like `nostartofline` without luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the following behavior, documented under `:help :make`:

> ```
>   7. If [!] is not given the first error is jumped to.
> ```

If you have no errors, Vim still somehow "jumps" to the first non-blank character in the current line (which may be a bug or an inconsequential side effect of the implementation).

If you want to keep the current cursor position, just use `:make!`.

Comment: Yes `:mak!` perfectly solves this problem. Thank you so much! I've struggled with this problem for months and sometimes it made me go mad ;-)

Comment: Glad I could help. This indeed is a bit unintuitive and quirky.